# xlrd excel sheet read error "open_workbook() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on_demand'""

Tags: python, xlrd

I am using xlrd to read cell values from excel sheets. My code follows, it was working fine before but don't know what changed in xlrd package, I am getting the error

"TypeError: open_workbook() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on_demand'"

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
bench = open_workbook('excelsheet.xls',on_demand=True)
for name in bench.sheet_names():
    sheetnew = bench.sheet_by_name(name)
    for i in range(0, 13):
        for cell in sheetnew.col(i):
            print cell.value
    bench.unload_sheet(name)
```

Comment: The `on_demand` keyword was added in version 0.7.1. Could you be using an older version of the xlrd package?

Comment: Actually I updated xlrd to the new version. Anyway I removed on_demand and removed unload and worked normally. I will add new code to the answer. Thanks for the reply Cairnarvon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my issue. Might be helpful for someone.

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
bench = open_workbook("excelsheet.xls")
for name in bench.sheet_names():
    sheetnew = bench.sheet_by_name(name)
    for i in range(0, 13):
        for cell in sheetnew.col(i):
            print cell.value
```

Comment: People don't think, I made a mistake in my code previously. My code was working fine before, after an upgrade I started getting this error and I had to change it to the new code as I mentioned. Why I got a -1 for my answer :(

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install xlrd==2.0.1
```

try to do this one

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).